# Looking for a way to to select multiple values in one column

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I apologize in advance for having no idea what I'm doing, I'm a complete novice. I've been asked to make a pivot table to show how many meetings each person has attended. We currently have 6 rows in which you can select the name of the attendee from a drop down list, all sourcing the same list of names.

[Here is what it looks like now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4197d.png)

I want to be able to use this data in a pivot table to show that Leslie attended X meetings etc but since Leslie's name could be in any of the rows I don't know how to do that in a pivot table. [When I drag the attendees rows into row labels it looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obygm.png)

My questions are:
1. Is there a way to select multiple names for who attended each meeting?
2. If not, does the set up of the attendees need to change ? Where would I begin?

Comment: Is each row a different meeting? If Leslie's name is in one of the `Other Attendees` columns but on a different row (or meeting) does it still need to be counted?

Comment: Yes, each row is for its own meeting.

Comment: It would still need to be counted as her attending each meeting each time. Would a screenshot of the full data sheet help?

Comment: Yes, that would help.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ONXtd.png (sorry for sensoring). When a meeting occurs we add it as a new row and put in the relevant info.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do. The best way to use a pivot table for your desired output is to rearrange your table with only one column for the attendees. The other attendees would need to be new rows. This link may be helpful for you: http://superuser.com/questions/635425/excel-pivot-table-categorical-variables-the-same-in-multiple-columns-histogram

Comment: You can use `COUNTIF` function in excel if you need to count the number of instances for a particular string in the range. e.g. `=COUNTIF(Your_Range_Here,"Leslie")`